# How to get values from dynamic array?

Tags: c#, json, object, dynamic, deserialization

I have deserialized the string by using the dynamic object.

Because property names dynamically changed. so can't able to deserialize with DTO objects.

Please find the code snippet:

```
var result = "[{\"series1\":\"{\\\"Category1\\\":4.3,\\\"Category2\\\":2.5,\\\"Category3\\\":3.5}\"},{\"series2\":\"{\\\"Category1\\\":2.4,\\\"Category2\\\":4.4,\\\"Category3\\\":1.8}\"},{\"series3\":\"{\\\"Category1\\\":2,\\\"Category2\\\":2,\\\"Category3\\\":3}\"}]");

var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic[]>(jsonText);
```

[image]

How to retrieve the series1 and category1, 2, 3 results?

Could you please help me to solve this?

Comment: Have you got json stuffed within json there?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you will have is you have json stuffed within json - obvious from the fact that you have double escape sequences there. So to get `series1` is fairly straightforward:

```
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic[]>(result);
Console.WriteLine(jsonResult[0]["series1"]);
```

But that itself is another json string. So you'll need to then parse that again to get `Category1` etc:

```
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic[]>(result);
var series1Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonResult[0]["series1"].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(series1Result["Category1"]); // 4.3
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hcACrM

Comment: Thanks jamiec for your response. Working awesome!

Answer (score 1):

As @Jamiec mentioned, there is inline JSON string to consider; so, you will have to deserialize twice.

For this answer, we'll avoid using `dynamic` altogether (without creating a custom JsonConverter) and avoid `JObject` (i.e. `IDictionary<string, JToken>`);

---

We'll define a Type for Categories. (For the second, iterative Deserialization)

```cs
    public class Categories
    {
        public double Category1 { get; set; }
        public double Category2 { get; set; }
        public double Category3 { get; set; }
    }
```

We'll replace `dynamic[]` with `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>>`.  Each dictionary has only one entry actually, so we'll simply join the `Keys` and `Values` using `string.Join()` in our iteration handling.

```cs
    var jsonText = "[{\"series1\":\"{\\\"Category1\\\":4.3,\\\"Category2\\\":2.5,\\\"Category3\\\":3.5}\"},{\"series2\":\"{\\\"Category1\\\":2.4,\\\"Category2\\\":4.4,\\\"Category3\\\":1.8}\"},{\"series3\":\"{\\\"Category1\\\":2,\\\"Category2\\\":2,\\\"Category3\\\":3}\"}]";

    var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>>>(jsonText);

    var r = jsonResult.Select(i => 
    {
        (string Series, Categories Categories) result = (string.Join(string.Empty, i.Keys), JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Categories>(string.Join(string.Empty, i.Values)));
        return result;
    }).ToArray();
```

(the last part uses a Deconstruct to `ValueTuple`)

`dynamic` here was actually a `JObject` which implements `IDictionary<string, JToken>`.  `JToken` is fairly flexible (infact it works with the snippet above - including `string.Join` usage), but as a matter of scope and preference we deserialized to a primitive `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Try jsonResult["series1"]["Category"]

Comment: Working great, Thanks for the response :)